# jQuery Cloning tr on a table

Tags: jquery, html

I want to clone my tr that has a class name cloneme inside a table please help me :(

here is my html code :

```
<table cellspacing="10" class="tbll" >
<tr>
<td>Choose Sub Heading</td><td><select name="subheading_id" style="min-width:145Px">
            <option value="1" Sub heading Me</option>
            <option value="2" Sub heading Me 2</option>     
    </select></td><td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr classs="cloneme">
<td>Choose Job Title</td><td><select name="jobtitles_id" style="min-width:145Px"><?php
            <option value="a" >A</option>   
            <option value="b" >B</option>   
            <option value="c" >C</option>       
                    <option value="none" >None</option> 
    </select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><div class="addjob" >Add another Job Title</div></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Here is my jQuery :

```
 $(".addjob").click(function(){
        var $clone = $('table.tbll tr.cloneme').clone();
         $('table.tbll').append($clone);    
 });
```

thanks in advance..

Comment: is there any particular position in your `table` that where you want to insert that `cloneme` tr?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo.  It's `class="cloneme"` not `classs="cloneme"`

jQuery was not able to find the `tr` that you wanted to clone.

http://jsfiddle.net/6r4Q4/1/

You also had some invalid html, but I don't think that was affecting it.

Comment: This fixes his issue but not his logic :). If click on the "add" part again, it adds two new rows, as there are two with the same class name. And the next click adds 4 and so on :)

Comment: @ryadavilli fixed with `$clone.removeClass('cloneme')`: http://jsfiddle.net/6r4Q4/4/

Comment: Cool. I would probably have gone with `var $clone = $('table.tbll tr.cloneme:first').clone();`, so he can retain the class definition as well if he needs it for something.

Comment: @ryadavilli fair enough, but I figure `.cloneme` indicates this is the table row that is to be cloned

Comment: Thank you all.. the problem was solved.. but i ask just one favor? on how to put remove on the end of each added element?

Comment: `$clone.append($("<input>").attr('type', 'submit').on('click', function () { $(this).parent().remove(); }));`

Answer (score 2):

```
$('table.tbll tr.cloneme').clone().appendTo('table.tbll');
```